# Generic method call, don't want to send in my types

Tags: c#, generics, cqrs

I'm experimenting with my Commands and some generic methods. I havn't used generics that much so now my brain is all messed up and hoping for some help.

What I want is the last test to pass. And return my TResult without me needing to supply the TCommand, TResult in the call.

```
invoker.Execute(command)
```

Since that command implements

```
: CommandBase<TestResult>
```

I though that the compiler would figure it out.

But the compiler only takes me the to the void method.

Huge thanks in advance!

Edit: The complete code is available at: http://codepaste.net/7rjg2e

**CommandInvoker**

```
public interface ICommandInvoker
{
    void Execute<TCommand>(TCommand command) where TCommand : ICommand;
    TResult Execute<TCommand, TResult>(TCommand command) where TCommand : ICommand<TResult>;
}

public class CommandInvoker : ICommandInvoker
{
    ...

    public void Execute<TCommand>(TCommand command) where TCommand : ICommand
    {
        var handler = _container.GetInstance<ICommandHandler<TCommand>>();
        handler.Handle(command);

        _session.SaveChanges();
    }

    public TResult Execute<TCommand, TResult>(TCommand command) where TCommand : ICommand<TResult>
    {
        var handler = _container.GetInstance<ICommandHandler<TCommand>>();
        handler.Handle(command);

        return command.Result;
    }
}
```

**Commands**

```
public interface ICommand
{
    bool IsValid { get; }
}

public interface ICommand<TResult> : ICommand
{
    TResult Result { get; }
}

public class CommandBase : ICommand
{
    public bool IsValid
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}

public class CommandBase<TResult> : ICommand<TResult>
{
    public bool IsValid { get { return false; } }
    public TResult Result { get; set; }
}
```

**CommandHandler**

```
public interface ICommandHandler<TCommand>
{
    void Handle(TCommand command);
}

public interface ICommandHandlerWithResult<TCommand, TResult> where TCommand : ICommand<TResult>
{
    void Handle(TCommand command);
}
```

**Test classes**

```
public class TestCommandWithResult : CommandBase<TestResult>
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class TestResult
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

**Test thats works**

```
[Test]
public void CanExcecuteWithResult()
{
    var command = new TestCommandWithResult { Id = "billy" };

    ObjectFactory.ResetDefaults();
    var mockHandler = new Mock<ICommandHandler<TestCommandWithResult>>();
    var sessionMock = new Mock<ISession>();
    ObjectFactory.Configure(x => x.For<ICommandHandler<TestCommandWithResult>>().Use(mockHandler.Object));

    var invoker = new CommandInvoker(ObjectFactory.Container, sessionMock.Object);
    var result = invoker.Execute<TestCommandWithResult, TestResult>(command);

    mockHandler.Verify(x => x.Handle(command));
}
```

**Test that I want to pass**

```
    [Test]
    public void CanExcecuteWithResult()
    {
        var command = new TestCommandWithResult { Id = "billy" };

        ObjectFactory.ResetDefaults();
        var mockHandler = new Mock<ICommandHandler<TestCommandWithResult>>();
        var sessionMock = new Mock<ISession>();
        ObjectFactory.Configure(x => x.For<ICommandHandler<TestCommandWithResult>>().Use(mockHandler.Object));

        var invoker = new CommandInvoker(ObjectFactory.Container, sessionMock.Object);
        var result = invoker.Execute(command); // <-- this only calls void version

        mockHandler.Verify(x => x.Handle(command));
    }
```

Comment: Interesting, does it work if you change the input arguments to the so the two methods do not have the same argument pattern?

Comment: What if you changed `var result = invoker.Execute(command);` to `TestResult result = invoker.Execute(command);`?

Comment: @Anastasiosyal: No. Return type doesn't play a role in type inference for determining applicable generic methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler cannot work out what TResult is unless TResult is passed in as a parameter. It is able to work out what what the type of TCommand is because that is passed in.

I don't see any reason why you need TCommand, you have an interface which is good enough, the only place you need the generic is on the return, As a suggestion try changing the signature of ICommandInvoker to which will give you what you want:

```c#
public interface ICommandInvoker
{
    void Execute(ICommand command);
    TResult Execute<TResult>(ICommand<TResult> command);
}
```

EDIT:

Actually I do see why you want TCommand because you are using the generic type on the container but my answer still stands. Can you pass a Type to your container instead of a generic?

```
public TResult Execute<TResult>(ICommand<TResult> command)
{
    Type commandHandlerType = typeof(ICommandHandler<>).MakeGenericType(command.GetType());

    var handler = _container.GetInstance(commandHandlerType);
    handler.Handle(command);

    return command.Result;
}
```

Comment: <Rant>If your going to down vote at least leave a comment for the good of the community.</Rant>

Comment: Thanks for taking your time, really appreciated. And thanks for giving my some code guidelines. With small modifications I've now managed to get it up running.

Answer (score 2):

This is from the type inference rules in the language specification.

The constraint `where TCommand : ICommand<TResult>` does not play a role in determining inferring the types.

Therefore, the type inference algorithm only uses

```
Execute<TComamnd, TResult>(TCommand command)
```

to deduce the type of `TResult`. but there is no information in the parameter `TCommand command` to determine the type `TResult`.

Therefore, the overload

```
TResult Execute<TCommand, TResult>(TCommand command)
```

is not an applicable function member because it can't figure out `TResult`.

From 7.5.2

> If type inference for a particular method fails, that method does not participate in overload resolution.

Here, the type inference fails for `TResult`.